# AWS S3 or Cloudfront Access denied ::: If refreshing on browser that contain url including path (i.e. domain.com/subdirectoryname)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

when accessing only domain name(i.e. domain.com), I have got a page that I wanna get

but when accessing domain that contains pathname(i.e. domain.com/subdirectoryname), I got an error message like below

`This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F7pM.png)

How Can I fix it? If clicking "enter image description here", you could see what I mean
more obviously

Comment: Are you trying to access a file on S3 (which don't exist) ? Or is it a dynamic path (like a single page web app) ? In that case you should configure cloudfront to redirect other path to your index

Comment: @AntoninRiche  Thanks for your comment!   I need to try what you advice

Answer (score 0):

@AntoninRiche First of all, Thank you for caring for me

when I configure AWS Cloudfront distribution the first time, I mistook that I connected AWS Cloudfront to just S3 bucket that AWS show me as a recommendation on the configuration page. but, I needed to connect Cloudfront to S3 bucket's "static hosting site"!

[My Fault] If you want to connect Cloudfront to S3 bucket's static site,
 Don't connect to just S3 bucket auto recommended by AWS like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuQjS.png)

[Solution] Connect to this URL from [S3 bucket site link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A94o2.png) please.